# How to substract previous row on a filtered Excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to a formula that calculates the difference between the current row and the imediatly previous *visible* row. The formula is not working when table is filtered.  It gives the difference the current row and the previous row by number irrespective of the Filter.

**Formula on cell D2 [diff]**

```
=IF(ROW()=2;[@[value]];[@[value]]-OFFSET([@[value]],-1,0))

    date    ID  value   diff
03/08/2020  1   120,00  120
03/08/2020  2   32,00   -88
03/08/2020  3   32,00   0
03/08/2020  3   12,00   -20
03/08/2020  4   13,00   1
03/08/2020  4   132,00  119
03/08/2020  4   112,00  -20
03/08/2020  4   323,00  211
```

[image]

Comment: The formula will subtract the previos row, irrespective of if it's filtered or not.. By "not working" do you mean you want to subtract the previous _visible_ row?

Comment: Yes @crhis, this is exactly what i would need, only apply formula to visible rows when filtered by ID for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OFFSET` doesn't do that.  You will need to modify the formula to detect the previous visible row.

I'd do that by adding a helper column `IsVisible` (which you can hide if you want) to the table that returns the row numder if visible, else 0.  Formula to do that is

```
=AGGREGATE(3,5,[@date])*ROW()
```

Then, the Diff formula looks up the Value from the row where `VisibleRow` is Max of `VisibleRow`'s < current row

```
=XLOOKUP(MAXIFS([IsVisible],[IsVisible],"<"&[@IsVisible]),[IsVisible],[Value],0,0)
```

Put that into your formula, which becomes

```
=IF(ROW()=ROW([#Headers])+1,[@Value],[@Value]-XLOOKUP(MAXIFS([IsVisible],[IsVisible],"<"&[@IsVisible]),[IsVisible],[Value],0,0))
```

<sub>Note 1, I've replaced the hard coded row 2 with a formula to remove the requirement the table starts at a specific row</sub>

<sub>Note2: the depends on the new functions `XLOOKUP` and `MAXIFS`, available in Excel 365.  It can be modified to use older formula if required</sub>

Unfiltered

[image]

Filtered

[image]

Comment: thanks! @chris i forgot to mention my Excel version (2010) i am going to work this formulas with my version.